# Changing user password through .net CF application

Tags: compact-framework

Our user password expire every so often, and we need a way for a user to set a new password inside the CF application( CF2.0 WIncE5.0, HP thin client).

Any ideas? My guess that I will have to use P/Invoke, and links would be appreciated.
THanks much!

Comment: You have a better chance at an answer if you provide more details.

For instance, what password are you wanting to change? My assumption is you mean a Windows domain password, but it's certainly not clear (could be SQL, or custom app, or something else). 

Be more specific and folks can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to a local operating system account password or a remote domain password, then please don't do that. It's very hard to get security right, this is a function much better left to the operating system tools and UI (how about invoking those?) and most importantly you'll be teaching your users to entrust their credentials to some_random_app. That's not cool...

Comment: He's talking about neither.  He means the password for the device he's running on.

Answer (score 0):

I won't have to do through CF after all